# Bundles not working for https pages ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a website that has some pages with HTTP and others pages with HTTPS, I implemented bundling and minification. Everything looks good under pages with HTTP but for pages under HTTPS bundles are not loaded correctly. Instead of load bundles like this

**http://website.com/bundles/SiteMaster?v=nz4Y8j9U0WYuL33BJCNnSjkpW-87hz-WiVvHU6Q9dZ01**

Bundles are loaded like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <!-- <script  language="javascript"> 
    window.location.replace("http://website.com/bundles/SiteMaster?v=nz4Y8j9U0WYuL33BJCNnSjkpW-87hz-WiVvHU6Q9dZ01") 
  </script> -->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

That is causing that SiteMaster bundle is not loaded and scripts are not recognized in DOM.

This is the way that I’m using to implement bundling:

In the Site.Master page:

```
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/SiteMaster")%>
```

BundleConfig.vb:

```
 bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/SiteMaster").Include(jQueryUrl) 
                .Include(jQueryUIUrl) 
                .Include("~/assets/javascript/lib/jquery.blockui.min.js") 
                .Include("~/assets/javascript/lib/iseMethods.js")
                .Include("~/assets/javascript/lib/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js") 
                .Include("~/assets/javascript/lib/superfish.js") )
```

I’m using framework 4.5 and WebForms.

I will appreciate your help.

Regards
Oscar.

Comment: Why are you loading your bundles with `window.location.replace`?

Comment: No, I'm not loading bundles with window.location.replace, I'm not sure if its the browser or the IIS that are doing that when the page is on HTTPS.